# Executing a shell command or Write a java program which performs the same operation

Tags: shell, sh, programming-languages

Which one is faster?
Using a shell command to perform a particular operation or writing a java program to perform the particular operation

Say we have to ping a particular web address which can be performed out by using the `ping` command or using the below mentioned Java code

I just wanna know which one consumes less time. Why?

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

class NewClass 
{ 
  // Sends ping request to a provided IP address 
  public static void sendPingRequest(String ipAddress) 
              throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
  { 
    InetAddress geek = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress); 
    System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress); 
    if (geek.isReachable(5000)) 
      System.out.println("Host is reachable"); 
    else
      System.out.println("Sorry ! We can't reach to this host"); 
  } 

  // Driver code 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
          throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
  { 
    String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"; 
    sendPingRequest(ipAddress); 

    ipAddress = "133.192.31.42"; 
    sendPingRequest(ipAddress); 

    ipAddress = "145.154.42.58"; 
    sendPingRequest(ipAddress); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: depends on the task. you can try and find out which one is faster on your own, you don't need to ask here

Comment: @Blackdeath: To write a program, which copies one file to another directory, it would take me a couple of seconds to write it as a shell program, and several minutes to write it in Java (including time for invoking the Java compiler etc.)

Answer (score 0):

JVM startup is quite expensive.

Unless you compile this with Graal into *native* code, the Java version doesn't have a chance on such *short lived* tasks. But unless you intend to execute this millions of times it will not matter, will it?